# cakephp2 how to send email using gmail smtp dynamically to a closed mailing list

Tags: email, cakephp, smtp, gmail, cakephp-2.0

Is there anyway in php or cakephp, to send email using smtp so that I can send email to a closed/internal mailing list. e.g:

In my company we have an email list: appsteam@company.com, which can only be send if a person also using xxx@company.com email. outside from that email it will be blocked. so in cakephp is there anyway to somehow take the user credential and send email under a company or maybe in gmail email, if it's google group

I think what I actually want will be, how to set up cakephp email so that it send just like I send directly from the email server, if I use gmail, then I want it looks like gmail (header, etc)

what the final code will do is supposedly, I will take credential from users for their email, and send the mail using that. here is my code for AbcComponent.php

```
/*
 * Abc components
 */
class AbcComponent extends Component {
    public $options = array();

    /**
     *  Constructor
     **/ 
    public function __construct(ComponentCollection $collection, $options = array()){
        parent::__construct($collection,$options);
        $this->options = array_merge($this->options, $options);
    }


    public function send_link ($user_email = null, $recipients = null, $subject = null, $message = null, $group_id = null, $user_id = null, $email_id = null, $download_password = null) {

        $final_subject = $subject;
        $final_recipients = $recipients;
        $final_message = $message;
        App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');            
        $recipients = str_replace(' ', '', $recipients);
        $recipients = explode(',', $recipients);
        $recipient_queue_num = 1;
        //Send the email one by one
        foreach ($recipients as $recipient) :           
            $email = new CakeEmail();
                    $email->delivery = 'smtp';
            //$email->from($user_email);
            $email->from('xxxxx@gmail.com');
            $email->to($recipient);

            $email->smtpOptions = array(
                'port'=>'465',
                'timeout'=>'30',
                'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
                'username'=>'xxxxx@gmail.com', //this will be later grab from dbase based on user
                'password'=>'password',
            );


            $email->subject($final_subject);
            $email->template('download_link_email');
            $email->emailFormat('both');
            $email->viewVars(array('final_message' => $final_message));         
            if($email->send()) {
                debug('email is sent');
            } else {
                debug('email is not sent');
            }

            //queue number increase for hashing purpose
            $recipient_queue_num++;
        endforeach;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->Email->delivery = ...
```

and later

```
$email = new CakeEmail();
```

Where is your "new object" statement before trying to access it?
You cannot just use it without.
You are also using both $this->Email and $email. This is probably your mistake (copy and paste errors).

```
$this->Email = new CakeEmail();
$this->Email->delivery = ...
...
```

"Indirect modification of overloaded property" is usually always an indicator of a non declared object that you are trying to access.

Comment: you were right, the error is gone now. Do you know why if I send to 1 email it work fine (abc@test.com), but it does not work for a mailing list such as (appsteam@test.com)

Comment: maybe you do not have the permission to do so (mailinglist could allow only specific senders), but that would be outside the scope of your question here.